# SQL with SQLite print message command

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I need to print a message between query results, but i can't find an appropriate SQL command that works with SQLite. For example if I have 2 tables, `BRANCH` and `STAFF`, and I need to return it's contents, i want the output to be like

`BRANCH data ------------
   *table content here*
 STAFF data -------------
   * table content here*`

How do I print `BRANCH data -----` message?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT "Your Message";
```

This Works just fine

Comment: Unfortunately, this now throws a parse error in later versions of SQLite (I'm on 3.44 right now) since the column "Your Message" doesn't exist.  You've still got my past upvote though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.print hello world o_O
```

See also `.help`.